# Add custom field in comments form

Tags: custom-post-types, custom-field, comments

how can I create a custom comment form, for a custom post type?

My final idea is to be able to add fields to qualify with stars.

Comment: in the `support` configuration you can set `comments` (https://codex.wordpress.org/Function_Reference/register_post_type) I never use it then I don't know which work remains to make in order to be useful.

Comment: @mmm this is for create custom post type, I need add custom fields for form commets..

Comment: the form is created by the function `comment_form` (in the file `wp-includes/comment-template.php`). Look this function, there are a lot of action and filter that you can use to custom the form.